# AxisFault: What does Server.userException mean?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

What does the following AxisFault mean?

Does it mean that:

- The request that is issued and received by the server and the server throws an (uncaught) exception, and therefore the exception is returned back to the client.

or

- My web app fails to create the SOAP request (so the request is not even sent from the client app)

NB. I'm new to web services

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1c) was found in the element content of the document.
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1c) was found in the element content of the document.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
        at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
```

Comment: If you're new to web services, you *really* want to avoid Axis. It's ancient, obsolete and rubbish.

Comment: That, unfortunately, is not an option :( It's already in the codebase, I'm not building anything new. I'm just trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @skaffman: That aside, which library would you suggest?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your application is respecting the extensibility of the SOAP fault codes, then it means that your server received a SOAP message but was unable to parse it.

The `invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1c) was found in the element content of the document` message should be a good indicator of what's wrong.

Your server is throwing an exception, which Axis sends to the client as a SOAP Fault. The faultCode indicates a Server error. Note that the `Server.userException` error code is not a standard value, it just is a more specific type of server fault code.

The default SOAP faultcode values are defined in an extensible manner that allows for new SOAP faultcode values to be defined. The mechanism uses a dot (.) to define more specific types of errors. It indicates that what is to the left of the dot is a more generic fault code value than the value to the right. See the specs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383510).

So I guess that `Server.userException` is a pertinent way of saying that the exception occured at the server but is not something strictly related to the server but related to what the client sent (`.userException`). At least that is what I think the authors had in mind. This is for you to discover :D.